# Find Author information from a series of textbook PDF's in java

Tags: java, pdf, search, find, author

Is there a reliable way to search through a folder of PDF textbooks and get back the author of each textbook by finding it within the PDF document?

My thought process for it to work would be to search for a keyword that is generally used before an author is named such as: author, written by, or any series of generally used terms before announcing the author. Once one of these keywords is found I would have it check the next 10 words for any that do not belong to a dictionary (since names usually don't match actual words) and then store those in a document with the PDF's title.

Alternatively if this proved incredibly inaccurate, I would have it highlight suggested author names with the entire sentence displayed in a frame for context, and then I would have 2 buttons, one for yes and one for no. if no, it would attempt to continue the search and eventually broaden the search if nothing matched.

My issue is that I have no idea what options are out there for use. Any free resources out there or hints to attempt this idea would help tremendously.

So far my best option I know of is just to turn the PDF into a text file temporarily and then search for that series of keywords to attempt this.

Comment: "So far my best option I know of is just to turn the PDF into a text file temporarily and then search for that series of keywords to attempt this. ". Yes, that is the answer to your question.

Comment: thanks! I was wondering if using named-entity recognition would be worth the increased coding difficulty for the possible increased accuracy. 

I was looking at either opencalais or alchemyAPI for this, if anybody has any experience with either of those let me know.

Comment: The first question actually is whether these files where created correctly :) PDF provides two ways to store things like author and so on as metadata: either using PDF objects (the Info Dictionary) or using XMP. If the information you are looking for would be there, your whole project could become a lot easier, but we'd need to see an example PDF to know.

Comment: The PDF comes from taking the physical textbook, stripping the spine and running the pages through a high-speed scanner. So there isn't any initial data about the PDF and usually it is done book by book by an actual person. I can assure that every one of the items will be a school textbook though, which I hope helps by providing a general format of where certain things can be located.

Comment: If the PDF is really a collection of scanned pages, you may need something that will OCR the text of the pages. There are a number of tools, [Abbyy](http://www.abbyy.com) has things for just about wherever you are on the scale (developer or consumer).

Otherwise, if the PDF contains real text, you could use something like [iText](http://itextpdf.com), [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org), or one of [Datalogics](http://www.datalogics.com/products/pdf/) solutions so that you don't convert the entire PDF to a text file and instead just look at a few of the pages, maybe like the first 10 or 15.